# Linux - Dovecot - not receive emails - Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I try install Mail server on Ubuntu, I've installed dovecot server.

- telnet localhost 110 - correct
- telnet mail.example.com 110 - correct

When I send email:

```
echo "Testicek" | mail -s "Dovecot test" info@example.com
```

And connect to the box info@example.com, I found it, so it's correct.

But when I send email from outside (forexample Gmail), to info@example.com is returned:

```
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7720 [example.com (1): Connection refused]
```

In log isn't something error, so I don't know where I can find problem, but I think so, it can be in setting of domain:

```
   1800 A 31.31.73.***
 * 1800 A 31.31.73.***
```

Subdomains is correctly serving on apache (LAMP stack) and send email via Squirrelmail was resulted correct domain too.

Comment: Do you actually have an MTA installed?

Comment: I've installed Postfix

Comment: Maybe I found problem - when I try **telnet localhost 25**, it's correct, but from outside **telnet domain.com 25**, it's return **Connection refused**, but for **telnet domain.com 110** its correct too

Answer (score 1):

I am no postfix or ubuntu expert, but I see the same thing often on CentOS with sendmail; for security, the MTA is configured not to listen on any address other than localhost by default.

[This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1379629.html) suggests that the trick is to change the line

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

Frosty, it might be worth your reading around a bit to discover the distinction between **sending** email, which is done via the MTA, and **reading** email, which is usually done with a POP and/or IMAP daemon.  The two functions are almost completely unrelated to each other, and you may find maintaining your mail server is easier if you do some background reading on which daemon(s) provide which service.

Comment: Thanks, I make dpkg-reconfigure postfix, and now I have inet_interfaces = all, but it still not work ;( Only from localhost it works, `echo "Testicek" | mail -s "Next test" info@domain.cz`

Comment: I make **dpkg-reconfigure postfix** and now it works, but I think that setting is same - I don't know hot, but it works :) Thanks all!